# Which statements about the War in Ukraine are now criminal in Russia?

Tags: law, russian-federation, propaganda, censorship

I read that the [Duma](https://www.tellerreport.com/news/2022-03-04-up-to-15-years-in-prison--duma-decides-on-high-penalties-for-%E2%80%9Cfake-news%E2%80%9D-about-the-russian-military.Sys3HOdy-q.html) in Russia has passed a law that provides for penalties of up to 15 years in prison for making certain statements about the war, for example using terms such as “attack,” “invasion,” and “declaration of war” in reporting on the war.

I haven't found the exact wording of the passed law and do not know if it specifically forbids certain phrases or how actually it is determined if a statement is criminal under this law. I found a [news article](http://duma.gov.ru/news/53620/) about the law on the Duma website, but only available in Russian. On this page there is are [some](https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/bill/464757-7) [links](https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/download/FDAA0D7C-679A-41DF-89A5-C29DD060FD82) that are [supposed to be](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71414/which-statements-about-the-war-in-ukraine-are-now-criminal-in-russia?noredirect=1#comment293197_71414) the law texts but I cannot load them (timing out). A screenshot of the texts is [available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ov08.jpg).

My guess is that speaking more or less faithfully about the war in Ukraine, the full-scale invasion initiated by an unprovoked attack last week is illegal now in Russia while what is allowed legally might not much have resemblance with what really happens.

What exactly does this new law forbid? How is it determined if a statement is illegal?

Which popular statements about the war that have for example been made on this site or elsewhere should one better not say aloud in Russia or else face a conviction under this law?

Comment: This question should definitely have the [censorship] tag, and I removed the [fake-news] tag since I think it's more for questions about *actual* fake-news and deliberate misinformation, rather than claiming accurate information is fake-news in order to censor it, but if you disagree, feel free to add that tag back

Comment: Here is a correct link: https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/bill/464757-7 (and here is a link to a final law project wording: https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/download/FDAA0D7C-679A-41DF-89A5-C29DD060FD82)

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov Thanks. These sites time out here. Could you maybe make some screenshots and upload at imgur for example.

Comment: It has several parts, first about "distribution of certainly false claims", second about "public defamation of Russian military actions" and the third about "public calls for new sanctions". All of it is deliberately vague and ruling is left up to a particular judge (or prosecutor's office).

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov Still, if you want, can you maybe translate and summarize the passages that you think are relevant in an answer. And if it is deliberately vague that is also interesting information in my eyes. A prime example of censorship, which is probably best if nobody knows what is exactly censored but exactly knows how big the penalty is.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/lhYZfIT I'm not trusting myself at a correct translation as my English skills are far from perfect

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov Many thanks. I included a link in the question. Anyone with Russian and English skills can then summarize the law and check if it says anything non-vague.

Comment: If you're just asking about what the law itself says then the [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) site might be a better place to ask, they are more likely to have people who know Russian law and where to find the actual legal documents.

Comment: Note that the rules supposedly extend to being penalized for using sources other than *official* Russian sources.

Comment: @Giter initially I wanted to know which true statements are now forbidden, and wanted to read about that in the law, but it is only available in Russian so far, so I need a translation first. However there are hints that it's written very vaguely, so probably nobody knows. It may be a catch all. Now I'm thinking about how to tweak the question. I definitely rather want to ask about the political implications of it. Maybe I should ask if that means that basically no Russian can have it's own opinion about the war and only if allowed to repeat the official propaganda or how far reaching it is.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That would explain how to determine what is allowed. Only that from official sources.

Comment: Citing only official sources is a different rule, imposed on news and media providers. And being a provider is determined by your auditory size, so a popular blogger can fall into that category (>3000 subscribers, that law was passed in 2014)

Comment: The first point of a new law penalise "public distribution of certainly false information as if it is truth" - sorry, my best attempt at a translation. Basically, if you make a public statement, tell that something is true, but it's not true - you're committing a crime. I cannot interpret (that's a question for a lawyer), who will decide "certainty" of falseness.

Comment: The second point of a new law penalise "public actions, aimed at discrediting a usage of Russian military for protection of interests of Russia, Russian citizens and world peace and international security, including appeals to stop or prevent such usage"; but there is a clause that such actions are undertaken by a person who already had being prosecuted for "a similar offence" or that such actions lead to a manslaughter or a harm to citizens property or health or riots or public security breaches or disturbances in infrastructures or disturbances in activity of various organisations.

Comment: The third point of a new law penalise appeals to introduction or prolongation of sanctions against Russia, Russian citizens or Russian organisations, made by a Russian citizen who already had being prosecuted for a similar offence in the last year.

Comment: I suppose your question would be criminal, spreading fake claims of a non-existing “War in Ukraine”.

Comment: I agree that while this question is probably on-topic here, it would be a better fit on Law.SE as it appears that you are looking at the law from a technical legal perspective (what criteria are banned by the text of the statute as interpreted by applicable Russian precedents and principles of statutory interpretation) rather than seeking a political analysis of what Russia is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gnasher729 but that's too vague for a true legal analysis. I think the OP is asking for legal details of how this law would work in an actual courtroom, based on knowledge of the text itself as well as existing Russian legal principles and procedures. That's really a legal question, not a political one. For example, who decides legally if a particular news item is false? Does the judge make that determination? Does a jury decide? Are expert witnesses with qualifications in journalism called up? Is such a determination delegated to senior officers in the military and/or the president?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Basically the question now boils down for me to: How does Russia define their version of "truth"? Obviously this law is so vague and the criteria so unclear that people just have to guess and probably decide to say nothing at all. It's ambiguous on purpose and the aim is simply to silence any other voice. As laws come by this is a shotgun. There really must be a term for that kind of arbitrariness in a legal system. And even what Russia regards as "truth" is really simple: whatever they say it is, it is.

Answer (score 5):

Most important points (I knew Russian language):

- you can't distribute fake information about usage Russian Armed Forces to protect interests of Russian Federation, protect international peace. This only applies if you say it's true information.
- you can't ask to prevent use Russian Armed Forces for issues above. You also can't discredit usage of Russian Armed Forces for issues above.
- you can't suggest to sanction Russia.

It is not said *directly* you can't call special military operation by any other name. It's assumed (this is in many russian non-state news, just one example:https://journal.tinkoff.ru/news/feik-ob-armii/ - this is from Tinkoff Journal, they mostly publish financial news because they run by large independent bank so you can consider that they have no direct interested in all of this and are as neutral as possible for Russian company) that any publication(including comments on web) about usage Russian Armed Forces without confirmation from Ministry of Defence or Russian state news sources could be considered sources if they are told as truth and not with doubt/as personal judgement.

How it really works? This law doesn't gets used yet as far as I'm aware.
Some previous ones are just used for block news sources for violations of law.
I suggest you look at human right activists article on this https://reports.ovdinfo.org/no-to-war#1 (there's English version - link at the top of page).

Comment: I also suspect it is somewhat vague on purpose as to scare as many people as possible

Comment: Yeah, basically everything except for the official version (and please with wholehearted enthusiasm) which overlaps with reality only partly if at all. I thought the law might be more specific but it's just a general purpose thought police. Even holding up a blank sheet of paper is too much according to the ovdinfo report you link.

Comment: Does it says that you can't call it a war in Russian (if you are in Russia)? Or in any language?  I've heard commentators (living in Russia) say the Latin "ante bellum," which literally translates as "before the war," in the course of their commentary.

Comment: @wrod, in any language (language is not specified). As for people in Russia call it "war" - right now this applies mostly to news sources (for some definition of such). Prosecution is at will. If it's news site which doesn't hosted in Russia, not officially registered as such and it's staff are either not in Russia or hide - it could be blocked if they want to use 'war'(example - meduza.io, ex-lenta.ru team, english/russian, they are latvian(AFAIR) registered news site on paper, they do call it war). As for regular persons - they will be prosecuted if goverment wants this.

Answer (score 4):

**Any** (mostly based on the chapter 280). I am not Russian of any kind but I am fluent in this language.

**The chapter 280** in your [linked text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ov08.jpg) offers the punishment for the public discreditation of the *usage of the Armed Forces of Russian Federation for the goal of defending the interests of Russian Federation and its citizens*.  It does not include the requirement that the "discreditation" should be based on knowingly or unknowingly the wrong information. **The person would be guilty also for telling the known and verified truth**, if this truth may cause people to stop respecting someone or believing in an idea or person. Nothing else is as discrediting as the truth may be.

The existence of this chapter probably explains why in some cases even displaying a blank poster with no text can be punishable ([source](https://www.hrw.org/video-photos/interactive/2022/08/22/what-can-get-you-trouble-anti-war-speech-russia)) so really remains a question if anything can be legally said apart copy-pasted official new releases.  [Attorneys](https://au.topnews.media/telegram-ukraine-news/%F0%9F%96%BC-lawyer-maria-bontsler-was-fined-in-kaliningrad-for-discrediting-the-russian-army/) cannot speak for they defendant if this defendant is an anti-war protester. [Deputies](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/09/europe/russia-officials-fined-for-putin-impeachment-call-intl/index.html) cannot do they job by raising doubts if the Ukraine campaign is managed well.

Using the word "war" is seen as discreditation so falls under this chapter as well. This is the "special operation". Russian opposition politician Yevgeny Roizman, has been [arrested](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russian-politician-detained-criticising-ukraine-invasion-2022-08-24/) for the single phrase, 'the invasion of Ukraine'. Due that I write "any", as once you use the word "war" that is in the title of the question the deal is done.

**The chapter 207** in the [linked text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ov08.jpg) talks about the *public distribution of the knowingly wrong information, related to the usage of the Armed Forces of Russian Federation for the goal of defending the interests of Russian Federation and its citizens*. The honesty of this chapter depends on how much is required to prove that the information is not just wrong but knowingly wrong. I am under impression that everything not in official news is automatically seen as "knowingly wrong". Statements like "Ukraine and its allies, including London, are threatening Russia for the last 1,000 years, to move NATO to our borders" ([source](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61272203)) may theoretically also qualify.  But likely would be assumed that the Russian propagandist sincerely believed NATO is the whole millennium old (only founded in 1949).

**The chapter 284** talks about the *suggestions for sanctions and other restrictions for Russian Federation and its citizens*. While Russian Federation itself is kind of strange place to call for sanctions on it, the most extreme opponents of war may possibly go that far.

Comment: You link points to a statement by the Russian representative to the UN - this is the *position of the Russian government*, but not the *law*, which is what the question asks.

Comment: I linked the better source. The answer itself remains correct.

Comment: I think what was needed here is the translation of the law (linked in the OP) and possibly a legal commentary on what it means and how it is actually applied. Your link does not contain this information.

Comment: I now provide I think enough samples on how this law is actually applied.

Comment: I changed my downvote to +1.

Answer (score 3):

You've got to take into account that in Russia the letter of the law diverges from the practice of the law very badly. It always did. Basically any statement against the war with Ukraine, no matter true or false, can land you in prison for years. Because, according to Kremlin, there is no war in Ukraine: it's a "special operation", and mere mentioning of the war, even simply saying "No to war!" will be judged as spreading false derogatory information about Russian forces, an imprisonable offense.

This "shut up or get imprisoned" is not an idle threat: [people have been sentenced](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-moscow-government-and-politics-235ad386cb40fe07357425fdfe6a80f2) for objecting to the war.

In Russia, it doesn't mean much what the law **says**: it's all about who is going to **interpret** it, and all the judges are Putin's appointees. You wouldn't believe the width of interpretation they are capable of.

Comment: Yes, I know that Russia doesn't have an independent justice system that honors the law, so in principle the answer to any question about laws in Russia is always the same. I initially asked this question because I thought Russian lawmakers have actually spelt out what is the "official truth" and what is not and I was curious about it, but that was a bit naive. They simply created a law to shut up any criticism in the population. In that regard there isn't even much difference to before. Russia became an authoritarian country already in the past.